# Am i using "EXCEPT" wrong? (SQL)

Tags: sql, sql-server

Why im getting only one resault out of using Except here?

Code:

```
Select C1.*
From tblCampaign as C1 
inner join tblCampaignInSocialMedia as CISM 
    On C1.campaignCode = CISM.campaignCode  
         --Except 
Select C2.*
From tblCampaign as C2 
inner join tblSentToMember as STM 
    On C2.campaignCode = STM.campaignCode
```

I'm trying to get those two rows of index's 6,7 :

[image: 1]

for some reason I get only one of the rows :

[image: 2]

the result I'm trying to get :

[image: 3]

First post here, be gentle :)

Comment: the next question will be how I post pictures normally

Answer (score 1):

The two rows that you want are identical.

`EXCEPT` removes duplicates, similar to `UNION`.  Unfortunately, SQL Server doesn't support an `EXCEPT ALL` operator.  You would need to rephrase the query, perhaps using `NOT EXISTS` instead of `EXCEPT`.

That would probably look something like this:

```
select c.*
from tblCampaign c
where exists (select 1 
              from tblCampaignInSocialMedia cism 
              where c.campaignCode = cism.campaignCode  
             ) and
      not exists (select 1
                  from tblSentToMember stm
                  where c.campaignCode = stm.campaignCode
                 );
```

Comment: I required to use one of the following :  except /  intersect /  union.

I can upload a picture of the diagram if it helps

Answer (score 0):

because `Except` returns distinct rows by comparing the results of two queries.

here is [microsoft refrence doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/set-operators-except-and-intersect-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)

probably you want to do this :

```
Select C1.*
From tblCampaign as C1 
inner join tblCampaignInSocialMedia as CISM 
    On C1.campaignCode = CISM.campaignCode  
    and c1.campaignCode not in (
                            SELECT c2.campaignCode
                            From tblCampaign as C2 
                            inner join tblSentToMember as STM 
                                On C2.campaignCode = STM.campaignCode
                            )
```

Comment: i did the exact same thing but I requested to use one of those ;  except / intersect / union as part of my solve lol..